# Dispose service layer object from viewmodel wpf and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing, idisposable, parallel.foreach

I'm new to `IDisposable` concept, I have the following scenario
facing an exception(stackover flow) when I dispose of the object.

I have to create multiple requests(parallel) to get a response from
API.

Like below:

### ViewModel

```
public vm 
{ 
    vm(IunityContainer container) { }

    public void somemethod 
    { 
        await ListofItems.ParallelForEachAsync(async item =>
        {
           try
           {
               using (var objectService = _container.Resolve<IobjectService>())
               {
                   var response = await objectService.GeAllItem(request);

                   concurrentBag.Add(response);
               }

           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {

               _logger.Error("Failed operation.", e);
           }

        },maxDegreeOfParallelism: 5);

    }
}
```

### Service.cs

```
public class Service : Idisposable
{


    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
           return;

        if (disposing)
        {
           this.Dispose();// not sure how to dispose the service layer object which is created 
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }


    public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


}
```

**Issue**: since I'm creating multiple objects by a parallel thread when end of the using (}) it throws stackoverflow exception.

solution: I wanted to dispose of "objectService" which is creating
each iteration of the foreach.

please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: [How to use Dispose And Finalize in C#](https://www.dotnetforall.com/how-to-use-dispose-and-finalize-csharp/).

Comment: Does your `Service` class contain any members that implement `IDisposable` or consume unmanaged memory directly? If not, it makes no sense to implement this interface. You should never call `Dispose` from `Dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

The stackoverflow error comes from the fact that `Dispose()` calls `Dispose(bool disposing)` which back again calls `Dispose()` on so on until you reach the end of the stack.

It is not a problem of multithreading.

If you look again at the example for `IDisposable` object given by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8 you will see that inside `if (disposing)` you need to call Dispose on all `IDisposable` **members** that the class contains and not on the class itself (not **this.Dispose()**)

Comment: Thanks for the response.   i don't know how to achieve this "you need to call Dispose on all IDisposable members" when i say dispose() it referring the class itself. please in my case what would be the implementation. i'm beginner of learning c# concepts.

Comment: Hi Manivannan, as much as I'd like to give you a full tutorial on the implementation on IDisposable pattern, I think you are better off reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose and learning about managed/unmanaged memory. If you have anymore question after reading this tutorial don't hesitate. Maybe one question I forgot to ask in the comments is why do you need Service class to be IDisposable, what was your first intent ?